# how to pass data over url in modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i don't know where's the missing link in my case. so, i want to pass data(id) over url and show it in modal view. the code so far is

```
<a data-id='$data[nip]' href='?v=biodata&n=$data[nip]' class='showme' data-toggle='modal' data-target='detilModal'>$data[nama]</a></td>
```

this is the js

```
 $(document).on("click", ".showme", function () {
     var nip = $(this).data('id');         
     window.history.pushState("","Title Here","?v=biodata&n="+nip);
     $('#detilModal').modal('show');
});
```

and this is the modal. it works fine when i reload the page and push button

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                    $nip = $_GET['n'];echo $nip ?>.....
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can set the 'nip' variable value to an element value/text inside the Modal.